# What is Morphia or Java driver query in one to many relation?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Suppose i have user collection and children collection.

Assume I have a specific user and children (which is the many side of user) has a field 
status of type string. I want to search for that child in user where status= "active".

Would the query be different if only one child in user can have status="active" at any time, although none of children may have status equal to "active" ?

Children are not embedded but reference in user.

This is my solution but does not look very efficient to me;

```
for (c : user.children) {
      if (c.status == "active") {
        child = c
      }
    }
```

Comment: please provide more details: are children embedded documents? post some example objects

Answer (score 0):

To search db directly you got add a "parentId" field to your Children class:

```
public class Children {
  public String status;
  public ObjectId parentId; // point to the parent of this child
}
```

Then here is the way to go:

If you use pure morphia:

```
Datastore ds = ...;
Children activeChild = ds.find(Children.class).filter("status", "active").filter("parentId", user.getId()).get();
```

If you are using Play!Framework with PlayMorphia module:

```
Children activeChild = Children.find("status,parentId", "active", user.getId()).get();
```